# What would be the scenarios were I should use "no joke this time" or "no jokes this time"?

Tags: word-choice

I would like to know if someone could provide me some examples of the usage of those phrases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're both proper English, and they mean different things.

*no joke this time* implies that one is being serious: what was just said (or about to be said) should not be taken as a joke.

> No joke this time, I just saw a giant 50 foot spider out in the backyard.

*no jokes this time* is more of a command: to stop joking around and be serious:

> Okay, no jokes this time, we need to get down to business and put this 50 foot paper-mache spider on the float for the parade.

Comment: Only that in the first case one often _is_ joking, see 'the boy that cried wolf' for the outcome.

Comment: @MrDisappointment Not necessarily: it's just as often used as filler like "seriously" or "hand to god".

Comment: I know _not necessarily_. ...just saying.